# Is it possible for ∇f=yi−xj

Tags: real-analysis, vector-analysis

Is it possible for a function $f(x,y)$ satisfying $\nabla f=y\mathbf{i}-x\mathbf{j}$ ?

Since $\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x \partial y}=-1$ and $\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y \partial x}=1$, thus $f$ should be singular.

I find a similar answer in wikipedia "Symmetry of Second derivatives",

$f(x,y)=\frac{xy(x^2-y^2)}{x^2+y^2}$ for $(x,y)\ne(0,0)$ and $f(x,y)=0$ for $(x,y)=(0,0)$, however, this function just satisfies at $(x,y)=(0,0)$.

Does anybody know a function satisfies the condition in the whole variables domain?

Comment: Cross-posted (and answered) at [physics.se]: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/291890/44126

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's impossible. The necessary an sufficient condition for the local existence of $f$ s.t. $\nabla f = \bf F$ for a given vector field $\bf F$ is $\partial_i F_j = \partial_j F_i$ (Poincaré's Lemma).